# C++ How to Implement Menu with Number and Letter Choices

Tags: c++, input, menu, char, int

I want to use a menu in C++ that has options both in letters and numbers.  For example, the output might be:

```
========================
(1) Do something
(2) Do something
(a) Do something
(b) Do something
========================
```

Is there a method for testing user input to determine if it is a char or int and handle it accordingly?

If I use:

```
int choice;
cin >> choice;
```

And the user inputs a char, of course cin will return an error.  I'm looking for a simple method to test user input for a digit or a character and have the program react differently based on that determination.

[UPDATE]

I've found the answer I was looking for.  Here's how I did it:

```
string choice;
cout << "Your choice: ";
cin >> choice;

if( isdigit(choice[0]) )
{
    theInt = stoi(wChoice);
    // do something with int
}
else if( choice[0] = 'a' )
    // do menu option a
```

Comment: `std::string choice;` might be the most flexible data type IMHO.

Comment: Why was this question down voted?  Some useful input would be nice.  =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use the method `isdigit` in the `ctype.h` to check if character is a decimal digit character, and the method `isalpha` to check if character is alphabetic.

Comment: _"`int` can't contain a `cha`r"_ That's certainly not the (whole) truth!

Comment: You are right. I took it for granted.

Answer (score 0):

> *"For example, there could be options: 1, 2, 3, n, s."*

The simplest solution I see is to have a menu selection code like

```
char choice;
std::cin >> choice;

switch(choice) {
case `1`:
   // Do menu option one
   break;
case `2`:
   // Do menu option two
   break;
case `3`:
   // Do menu option three
   break;
case `n`:
   // Do menu option "n"
   break;
case `s`:
   // Do menu option "s"
   break;
}
```

---

If you need to handle numeric choices bigger than `9`, you simply use a `std::string` as input field:

```
std::string choice; // <<<    
std::cin >> choice;
```

in turn a `switch` statement cannot be used any more and you have to change it to an `if/else if/else` cascade:

```
if(choice == "1") {
   // Do menu option one
}
else if(choice == "2") {
   // Do menu option two
}
// ...
else if(choice == "42") {
   // Do menu option fortytwo
}
else if(choice == "n") {
   // Do menu option "n"
}
else if(choice == "s") {
   // Do menu option "s"
}
```

Comment: I know I could use a switch statement to handle this, but I was hoping to find a better solution since I want to take the integer choices and use them in a vector like vector[choice], but the non-number inputs would be used differently.

Answer (score -1):

For this, you'll need to read in the input as a string, then parse it to see if it's an alphabetic character or if it's a numeric string.  Something along the lines of this (warning, I'm mostly a C programmer, so using C-strings instead of real strings):

```
#define INPUT_SIZE 8
char input[INPUT_SIZE]; // change size as appropriate
cin.getline(input, INPUT_SIZE);

if (cin.good())
  if(input[0] >= '0' && input[0] <= '9') {
      int value = atoi(input);
  } else if(input[0] >= 'a' && input[0] <= 'z') {
      char value = input;
  }
}
```

Naturally, values need different names and actual code paths to deal with them, especially as C++ doesn't have a good built-in "either" type that I know of.

Alternatively, just treat everything as a character, assuming all numeric options are a single character, and test as '0' instead of 0.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful feedback, panda.  It seems that we were attempting to solve slightly different problems - I thought that the question may have been dealing with dynamic menu generation from some data, though admittedly there is no point in converting to int in the numeric case.

Comment: De nada! http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/giant-panda-bear-pictures0.jpg Why bothering with `char input[INPUT_SIZE];` char arrays anyway?